# Reset desktop on ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, 21.04

I upgraded my workstation from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 21.04.

Everything works fine except the desktop had some icons/settings problems. I resolved some of them by running:

```
dconf reset -f /
systemctl restart gdm3
```

I can't open the Settings (it just shows a loading wheel and then just stops), and I still have some issues with icons as seen here (this is the terminal):

[image: terminal with problematic icons]

When I log in as root, which is a local user, everything works fine. But when I login with my user, which is a remote user, I get these problems.

I assume that in my home directory there's a file responsible for some desktop settings that is compatible with Ubuntu 18.04 but causes problems with Ubuntu 21.04. I'm just not sure what it is.

Does anyone happen to know what that file may be? What should I do?

Huge thanks ahead.

Comment: The config file is usually stored in the users homedir, find it and delete/adjust it.